# relocation error: libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference

Tags: linux, electron, centos6

Our company made one application which work on electron version 1.8.2. When someone open the application on Centos 6.x below error is occur

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

I made a script with the help of [link](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1172):

```
#!/bin/bash
LDDVERSION="$(ldd --version | awk '/ldd/{print $NF}')"
requiredVersion=2.17
SRC_PATH=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )
glibpath=$SRC_PATH/gcc
export glibpath="$SRC_PATH/gcc"
if (( $(echo "$LDDVERSION < $requiredVersion" |bc -l) )); then
echo "Loading GCC"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/glib-2.49.4-kgesagxmtbemim2denf65on4iixy3miy/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/libffi-3.2.1-wk2luzhfdpbievnqqtu24pi774esyqye/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/pcre-8.39-itdbuzevbtzqeqrvna47wstwczud67wx/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/gettext-0.19.8.1-aoweyaoufujdlobl7dphb2gdrhuhikil/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
fi
$SRC_PATH/myapp
```

It works fine on electron version 1.8.2 but when I change electron version 1.8.3. Below error is getting.

> 'libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.15' not found`

Then I checked via command:

```
**$ strings libc.so.6 |grep GLIBC**
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

After some research I find libc.so.6 file in Google Chrome lib folder

```
strings /opt/google/chrome/lib/libc.so.6 |grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.2.6
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.3.3
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.5
GLIBC_2.6
GLIBC_2.7
GLIBC_2.8
GLIBC_2.9
GLIBC_2.10
GLIBC_2.11
GLIBC_2.12
GLIBC_2.13
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

So I changed this file to my old libc.so.6 file. After that I facing below error.

> relocation error: libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
>   ./myscript.sh: line 14: 30656 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $SRC_PATH/myapp

Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Can you try to run the command as a different user? 


I have a very similar error with 6.1, 7.4 and 7.6 where I get this relocation error, but with a different user the problem does not exhibit itself. I have been comparing the environment of the two users and still haven't found what's different or toxic.

Comment: Also, can you try to run where you are quite certain that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is NOT terminated with the ":"? Your script above may have this case. Example in my case LD_LIBRARY_PATH=fred works, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=fred: fails, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=fred:barney works.